# Connection string to read from one topic and write to another

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm using azure service bus topics and need to generate connection string which allows for one topic only to write and only to read from second. 
I know that I can group both topics into one namespace and generate connection string for this namespace, but in this case permissions will be to broad - writes and reads will be posiblle from both topics.
Is three any option to get fine-grade connection string in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure rules at the namespace level, on Service Bus queues and topics.

To achieve what you need to achieve, you'd need two Shared [Access Authorization Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#shared-access-authorization-policies):

1. One to write to a topic you want to give access to
2. One to read from the subscription you want to give access to (note you cannot read from a topic).

This would mean creating sender and receiver using different connections strings.

Comment: But is there any option to create single connection string which allows to write to one topic and to read from subscription on another topic?

Comment: No. Please see my answer and the link to the documentation.